# com.atomikos.datasource.ResourceException: XA resource 'ddpDataSource': resume for XID '' raised -4: the supplied XID is invalid for this XA resource

Tags: spring, atomikos

Now, we are facing one XID issues like below by using atomikos:5.0.9 with Spring framework 5.3.23.

We try to migrate atomikos:4.0.6 to atomikos:5.0.9, but unfortunately we have faced the below issue.

So, does anyone know what is happened?

**Error log**

```
Caused by: com.atomikos.datasource.ResourceException: XA resource 'ddpDataSource': resume for XID 'XID: 3130302E3130332E31352E38322E746D313730383535393630343130333031353332:3130302E3130332E31352E38322E746D3137333
2' raised -4: the supplied XID is invalid for this XA resource
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.resume(XAResourceTransaction.java:225) ~[transactions-jta-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler.<init>(BranchEnlistedStateHandler.java:40) ~[transactions-jta-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler.checkEnlistBeforeUse(NotInBranchStateHandler.java:46) ~[transactions-jta-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TransactionContext.checkEnlistBeforeUse(TransactionContext.java:58) ~[transactions-jta-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.SessionHandleState.notifyBeforeUse(SessionHandleState.java:163) ~[transactions-jta-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.jdbc.internal.AtomikosJdbcConnectionProxy.enlist(AtomikosJdbcConnectionProxy.java:88) ~[transactions-jdbc-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.jdbc.internal.AtomikosJdbcConnectionProxy.updateTransactionContext(AtomikosJdbcConnectionProxy.java:61) ~[transactions-jdbc-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.atomikos.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcConnectionProxy.prepareStatement(AbstractJdbcConnectionProxy.java:64) ~[transactions-jdbc-5.0.9.jar:?]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor215.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_342]
```

**atomikos:5.0.9 release note** - https://www.atomikos.com/Blog/TransactionsEssentials5dot0dot9

**pom.xml**

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-jms</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
            <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```